# Directional derivative only for certain directionvectors

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, differential-topology, partial-derivative

How should i do this, i'm lost? Pointers but also full solutions are welcome.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried writing down the definition of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{u}}$ to see why it might fail for $\mathbf{u}\neq (1,0), (0,1)$?

Comment: Note that the function is discontinuous at the origin along all lines other than the coordinate axes.

Comment: If $(u1)^2 +(u2)^2=1$, then why wouldn't this be true also for(-1,0) and (0,-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Change the Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates as $$x_1=r\cos\phi\\x_2=r\sin\phi$$and rewrite the limit as a function of $\phi$ when $r\to 0$. For what values of $\phi$ does the limit exist?